# Why showing this error in running mptcp?

Tags: software-installation, patch, ns2

Could anybody please help me. Why showing this error while I am trying to run the command for sample mptcp?

The file is available here https://github.com/wangzhizhou/Network-Simulator-Installation-Guideline-For-Ubuntu/blob/master/README.md

```
invalid command name "Agent/TCP/FullTcp/Sack/Multipath"
    while executing
"Agent/TCP/FullTcp/Sack/Multipath create _o292 "
    invoked from within
"catch "$className create $o $args" msg"
    invoked from within
"if [catch "$className create $o $args" msg] {
if [string match "__FAILED_SHADOW_OBJECT_" $msg] {
delete $o
return ""
}
global errorInfo
error "class $..."
    (procedure "new" line 3)
    invoked from within
"new Agent/TCP/FullTcp/Sack/Multipath"
    invoked from within
"set tcp0 [new Agent/TCP/FullTcp/Sack/Multipath]"
    (file "mptcp-sample.tcl" line 98)
```

Comment: `Sack1` : Looks like an edited version of "mptcp-sample.tcl". .... Suggest : Upload the file as mptcp-sample-1.tcl, and edit your question to include the new information.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Sir, actually I have tried to change the sack. but that was not my question. I have mistakenly given that error's example. Actually I am trying to run the "mptcp-sample.tcl" file but its is showing that error which I have edited in the question. Could you please help to know why it is showing this problem, sir.

Comment: »»invalid command name "Agent/TCP/FullTcp/Sack/Multipath«« : You are using a copy of the execuable **ns** with no MPTCP. Or you have a failed build. ... ns2-INFO https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FCjn-9fkR7tKeqClUpHsleaEdnoKRZzq/view?usp=sharing .... `ns-2.35` the 2014 update https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNVVlxR0ZNRGVORjQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you, Sir, It is working now. I am very much happy. I followed your ns2-INFO file. 

Sir, I have another question. If I want to use the satellite node as a middle node (relay) of MPTCP then how can I define it? 
Maybe it is an irrelevant question here but if I get any suggestion or where to ask or anything which can help me to find it from you, it would be very helpful to me. 
Actually I think you are the person who can guide me to this and who talks very informative.

Comment: I saw your question (some days ago) with "mptcp satellite" elsewhere and tested MPTCP with some of the default ns2/tcl/ex/*satellite* : No luck with any edited satellite simulation, sorry.

Comment: @KnudLarsen yes, you are right. I am trying this thing for a long time but not getting any way to complete it. 
Could you please share any source codes where they have done something related to this sir?  Maybe if you could share any edited simulation, it could help me to understand the system how to do this. 
Thank you in advance, sir.

Comment: Test directories `mptcp-satelite-test.tar.gz` https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ddil3n4G77FPDCUI8QawNBuGobF1Jz6y/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Knud Larsen Thank you very much, sir. It would be a great help to me. May I have your email address, if it does not break the rules of our community. My email address is bappy.yousuf@gmail.com
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Here is the link of the paper on which I am trying to work. Maybe it could be a reference to know more.

`https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=8646484`

Comment: Please also ask at the "ns2 Forum" https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ns-users ... ( with reference to this very thread.) ...

Comment: You are very kind Sir.